# Does using DTOs everywhere affect memory usage on jvm?

Tags: java, performance, memory, jvm, modelmapper

So my question is in my projects, I am using the model mapper in my Service classes. So when a service calls the Dao layer (Which actually just a JPA Repository interface), Dao layer returns the entity successfully now instead of just returning the actual entity, I convert it into a DTO first(Which is a just exact copy of entity)using the model mapper of java.
Because I don't want to expose my Entity directly.

**Code example:**

```
public class FormService {

    @Autowired
    private FormMasterDao formMasterDao;

    @Autowired
    private ModelMapper mapper;

    public FormMasterDTO save(FormMasterDTO formMasterDTO) {

        FormMaster formMaster = buildFormMaster(formMasterDTO);

        return convertToFormMasterDTO(formMasterDao.save(formMaster));
    }


    public List<FormMasterDTO> findById(String id) {

        return formMasterDao.findByIdIn(id)
                .stream()
                .map(this::convertToFormMasterDTO)
                .collect(toList());    }

    public void updateAll(List<FormMasterDTO> formMasterDTOList) {

        formMasterDao.saveAll(formMasterDTOList.stream()
                .map(this::convertToFormMaster)
                .collect(toList()));
    }

    public FormMasterDTO update(FormMasterDTO formMasterDTO) {
        return convertToFormMasterDTO(formMasterDao.save(convertToFormMaster(formMasterDTO)));
    }

    private FormMasterDTO convertToFormMasterDTO(FormMaster formMaster) {
        return mapper.map(formMaster, FormMasterDTO.class);
    }

    private FormMaster convertToFormMaster(FormMasterDTO formMasterDTO) {
        return mapper.map(formMasterDTO, FormMaster.class);
    }

}
```

I found this approach useful because If many developers working and writing code they are not allowed to play directly with the entities.

But I want to know, is using this approach is bad? Will, it affects the JVM because everytime if someone hits the service I am converting it into a DTO.

Comment: Unless you have a performance profile of a realistic load which tells you, you have a problem with the number of objects being created, there is a 99% chance it's just a guess to assume it could be a problem. I suggest running your application with flight recorder to see where your application is spending it's time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are worried about the time-cost of converting from a pure JPA object to a DTO, then do not. Here is why.

**Object allocation is indeed slow, compared to many other operations, but not slow at all compared to IO.** I am sure your JPA service is going to fetch something from database. If I am correct, then suddenly the time you spend on new object allocation (and the incurred GC cost later) will be less than 0.01% of the time you just spent on the DB operation itself.

In case you optimize for speed, memory allocation is a good idea to reduce, but should by far not be the first thing you do. It makes sense to do only after you optimized out much more costly operations, like your DB queries.

**Disclaimer:**
There is a case where your DTO would prove to be costly. If you would happen to use lazy-loading within your JPA objects, the DTO-conversion you are about to do would fully defeat that. Lazy-loading would allow JPA to *not fetch* certain subelements of your JPA objectgraph, but as part the DTO-conversion you would request the "optional" data every single time, which in turn would put you back where you started before starting to use `Lazy`.

Comment: I agree with you @Gergely, but here in my problem, I am converting each Entity back to A DTO by using model mapper.... Is it really will affect the system? Actually, I am doing to follow single responsibility. for example, You just give id I will give the copy DTO of that entity you play with it. But giving a copy each time requires model mapper. So does it really affects the system? I have seen people using collection unnecessarily.

Comment: I am not fully sure if I understood your comment but: Do you have a code that return full objects, each time it is given an ID? If yes, then it is potentially a performance-nightmare yes. Without proper caching (which is not trivial do well), you will be constantly fetching things from the database. That (and not the DTO conversion itself) will be a horribly slow thing. If you update this question (or better create a new one), we will find a more optimal solution than that.